# Where are Swift API docs?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Where can I find Apple Swift API Docs,
for example I want to find documents for **sorted** function and it's paramteres, where are these docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this.

- One is to look at the documentation. It's on your computer; use the documentation window in Xcode and work your way down to Xcode 6 library > Languages & Utilities ? Swift > Reference > Swift Standard Library Reference.

[image]

- The other, which is often preferable (though it requires more sophistication), is to look at the Swift header. It's on your computer too, but it's harder to get a look at. What I do is use the `println` function and command-click on `println`, which switches to the header.

Comment: The second approach is perfect, but how do access first approach?

Comment: I don't see what further I can say. Do you need someone to place your fingers on the keys?

Comment: Ah, just found it, tx!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: Also available as web page: Go to https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/ (which is a good starting point for all Swift related information) and click on "Swift Standard Library Reference".